# Xampp with php is not running

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am new to php i have downloaded the php and i have started the Apache and mysql in Xampp server. Now I have created the folder called hello and i have a file index.php. Now if i run using this url http://localhost/hello/index.php it shows the Error message of.

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.5.38[image]
How to solve this.

Comment: Where is your `hello` folder? With the default  installation path it should be in `C:\xampp\htdocs\hello\index.php`

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\hello it is in this location

Comment: Is http://localhost working? (you should see some welcome page from xampp)

Comment: how to check that

Comment: 4:18:35 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
4:18:35 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
4:18:35 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
4:18:35 PM  [Apache]  XAMPP Apache is already running on port 80
4:18:35 PM  [Apache]  XAMPP Apache is already running on port 443
4:18:36 PM  [mysql]  XAMPP MySQL is already running on port 3306
4:18:36 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
4:18:36 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
 am getting this

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Xampp with administrator i think it will solve this problem

Or HTACCESS in root folder

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: If thats not working keep in mind that ur htaccess is in the root folder

Comment: i tried running as adminstrator still it shows the same

Comment: I dont have the htaccess folder

Comment: I want run the php file. I have the php,Apache,mysql, Xampp